# Can we have a variable in the option part of Buildout's config file?

Tags: python, buildout

Python's [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/) configuration file allows us to avoid repetition of *values* by allowing a special syntax known as [variable substitution](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/topics/variables-extending-and-substitutions.html) which is of the form `${SECTION:OPTION}`

This is an example which allows us to avoid repeating the word `experiment`:

```
[context]
name = experiment

[db]
server = ${context:name}
```

Is it possible to use substitution for the *option* itself?

For example:

```
[soures]
${context:name} = https://git.com/${context:name}.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, variable expansion in keys is not supported; the feature is actually named [***value*** substitions](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/topics/variables-extending-and-substitutions.html#value-substitutions), to make it clear the syntax only applies to values:

> When supplying values in a configuration, you can include values from other options using the syntax:
>
> ```
> ${SECTION:OPTION}
> ```

The [*options* syntax](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/reference.html#options) also explicitly excludes the characters needed to make substitutions possible:

> Options are specified with an option name followed by an equal sign and a value:
>
> ```
> parts = py
> ```
>
> Option names may have any characters other than whitespace, square braces, curly braces, equal signs, or colons

with an exception noted for the [short-hand `<part-dependencies>` syntax](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/reference.html#special-implication-syntax-for-the-part-dependencies-option).

So, in the end, when [variable substitutions are applied in buildout](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/9418699ca136e7eb21629712766f999ea14147f6/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py#L1419-L1422), the code looks for the `${` part of the syntax in the values only:

```
# force substitutions
for k, v in sorted(self._raw.items()):
    if '${' in v:
        self._dosub(k, v)
```

Comment: Thank You so much! Too bad that I read Value Substitution as Variable Substitution :-)